# Elementary Markov Chain Question

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains, linear-algebra

Are any general conditions known on a finite transition nxn matrix that ensure that there exists at least one mth root which is also a transition matrix? It is easy to construct a 3x3 , diagonally dominant, transition matrix with distinct, real eigenvalues but no transition matrix, square root.

Comment: I added some obvious tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, as far as I know it is an open problem; there are no simple general conditions.

You can find some work on the problem, including sufficient criteria, counterexamples and some plots that give heuristics, on http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~lijing/papers/hili11.pdf